# What is the correct way to update Vitest?

Tags: vitest

I appear to be running Vitest V0.23.4 - at least that's what gets displayed each time I start my tests - and the current version is 1.2.2 so I am rather far behind the current version. Assuming there's no harm in upgrading to the latest version - please correct me if I'm wrong - I'd like to know how to update Vitest? My project is just a week or so old and I chose Vitest when I created the project so I'm surprised I got such a back-level version of Vitest.

I'm new to Vitest and am not very far advanced with Javascript frameworks in general so forgive me for asking such a basic question. I don't see the issue discussed in the Vitest manual or its Github repo so I'm guessing the answer is blindingly obvious to everyone - except me!